# Как исправить ошибку Cannot modify header information в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

При попытке сделать редирект в кастомном плагине получаю ошибку.
Проверил все файлы, перед тегом `<?php` пробелов нет, данные никакие не вывожу. Другие плагины отключил.

```
wp-1 | [Thu Jul 28 11:49:13.550986 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 24] [client 172.21.0.1:38412] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/template.php:2546) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1424, referer: http://localhost:8081/wp-admin/admin.php?page=kws
```

Файлы плагина.

```php
function run_countries() {
    $plugin = new Plugin();
    $plugin->run();
}

add_action( 'init', 'run_countries' );
```

```php
class Plugin {
    public function __construct() {
        // ...
        $this->load_dependencies();
        $this->define_admin_hooks();

    }

    private function load_dependencies() {

        require_once plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . 'inc/class-plugin-loader.php';

        require_once plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . 'admin/class-admin.php';

        $this->loader = new Plugin_Loader();

    }
    private function define_admin_hooks() {

        $plugin_admin = new Admin( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );

        $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_styles' );
        $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_scripts' );

        $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_menu', $plugin_admin, 'add_admin_menu' );
}

}
```

```php
if ( ! class_exists( 'Admin_Request_Handler' ) ) {
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'inc/class-admin-request-handler.php';
}
class Admin {
    public function __construct( $plugin_name, $version ) {
        $this->request_handler = new Admin_Request_Handler();
    }
    public function add_admin_menu() {
        add_menu_page(
            'Domains',
            'Domains',
            static::CAPABILITY,
            static::SLUG,
            [ $this->request_handler, 'show_table' ],
        );
}
}
```

```php
class Admin_Request_Handler {
    public function show_table() {
        $table = new Domains_List_Table();

        $table->process_bulk_action();

        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] ) ) {
            wp_redirect( remove_query_arg(
                [
                    '_wp_http_referer',
                    '_wpnonce',
                ],
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
            ) );
        }

        require_once plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . 'partials/page-list.php';
    }
}
```

Что еще может быть причиной? И как исправить, кроме `ob_start()` на **init**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add_admin_page` ничего не делает, а просто добавляет меню во внутренние структуры. Не вызывает ваш callback, а добавляет `add_action( $hookname, $callback );`.

Существенно позже, когда уже половина страницы админки выведена и дошла очередь до вашего меню, срабатывает do_action с вашим callback. Естественно, вы получаете описанный в вопросе результат.

Логика неправильная. callback в меню вообще не для редиректа.

Comment: Можете объяснить как делать правильно? Я обновил пример `show_table`, он не только делает редирект, но и выводит таблицу.
Callback должен просто возвращать шаблон/контент?
А где тогда обрабатывать GET и делать редиректы?
В том же методе `process_bulk_action` они так же присутствуют.

Comment: Как вариант подсмотрел в плагине contact-form-7, для вывода страницы в `add_sumbenu_page` используется одна функция и к ней "цепляется" **load-{$page-hook}** где выполняются редиректы.
Повторил у себя и все заработало. Еще как вариант, подключают файл в самом начале с проверками и редиректами. Являются ли такие варианты правильными?

Comment: По-разному можно. Надо только понимать систему хуков, когда что запускается. load-{$page-hook} нормально.